# Is the Qt event loop the same kind of abstraction like in other languages/frameworks?

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling, event-loop

As an example to my question, I want to share an often recommended example for API purposes when we just want to get some data from HTTP server:

```cpp
QNetworkRequest req;
QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
QNetworkReply *reply;
QEventLoop eventLoop;
QString buffer;
QString url;

QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
url = "https://api.test.com/text1";
req.setUrl(QUrl(url);
reply = mgr.get(req);
eventLoop.exec();
buffer = reply->readAll();
delete reply;
```

It's working, but from the information around the web it's considered to be a wrong habit and should be avoided.

Before, I used to wonder why the while loop example that some people try to apply, doesn't work, as I understand now that we're blocking everything, stack and also events (because stack needs to be served first, then event queue?) don't work:

```cpp
url = "https://api.test.com/text1";
req.setUrl(QUrl(url);
reply = mgr.get(req);
while (!reply->isFinished()){}
buffer = reply->readAll();
delete reply;
```

and then we come to another working solution that should be fine and safe:

```cpp
url = "https://api.test.com/text1";
req.setUrl(QUrl(url);
reply = mgr.get(req);
while (!reply->isFinished()){
 QApplication::processEvents();
}
buffer = reply->readAll();
delete reply;
```

The above example works fine, so I'm rather going to stay with it, however there is an option to of course do this with signals and slots:

```cpp
void binConCl::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
 buffer = reply->readAll();
 delete reply;
}

QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
url = "https://api.test.com/text1";
req.setUrl(QUrl(url);
reply = mgr.get(req);
```

Of course buffer and reply should be declared then for example in a header file as private variables for a class where these functions are.

This example adds more work for my purposes as I'm invoking the function including all the connection, request sending and so on, and then I'm parsing the buffer as JSON object and I need to return it, so I would have to send another signal from `replyFinished` back to GUI, but I think that's the Qt way and correct way. What do you think?

Do I understand how an event loop works well? An event loop is also kind of a while loop checking around all the stuff invoked, signals etc.

So when we use like in the first example, the inner QEventLoop, do we invoke a new thread or kind of new stack/queue in the same thread (is it possible at all?)?.

I watched [this video](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=767) from JavaScript conference and it's explained quite in an understandable way, this fragment is around 1-2 minutes, but I still have doubts.

Comment: If re-entering the event loop, you have to be very sure no non-re-entrant function gets called re-entrantly. This can be surprisingly hard to be sure of, and easy to break when code evolves. Much more robust to just not do it.

Answer (score 2):

an eventloop has 3 jobs.

1. get messages (signals) from the operating system and other sources.
2. dispatch those messages to the appropriate handlers (SLOTS).
3. sleep until more work is available.

a QEventLoop allows you to create a local eventloop that will call the `QApplication` event loop to do all 3 tasks, but nesting loops creates a set of problems and you should avoid nesting eventloops, which is why abusing `QEventLoop` is discouraged.

a naive implementation where you only call `QApplication::processEvents();` in a loop doesn't do the sleep part, and without sleeps your CPU will be pinned at 100% and waste a lot of power doing nothing, [the docs discourages calling `processEvents` directly in a loop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents).

the solution of handling the result in a SLOT is the correct approach as recommended in the docs, as you.

1. avoid local event loops
2. allow your CPU to sleep (think of phones and laptops with limited batteries)

if your functions MUST maintain state and cannot be split to two functions then you should put it on a [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html),and run the `QEventLoop` there, where you are safe from the problems of nested eventloops, but you should limit the number of threads you create as threads are resource-intensive (compared to the SLOTS approach), and keep in mind that you will eventually be sending a signal to the main thread to update the GUI as you can't update the GUI from a different thread.

Comment: Thank you, well, I think I'm going to try to design it with signals/slots pattern in the same thread as my API calls don't take much time. However when thinking about event loops in Qt as its abstraction/design, why actually QeventLoop does not block main thread/eventLoop (first code example) like simple while loop does, so main thread can server QNetworkReply finished() signal and quit nested QeventLoop? Where does it run? And why it does block the stack but not the event loop from the main thread?

Comment: @Jacob when you `exec` you application, there is something like a `QEventLoop` that is running and calling `QApplication::processEvents`, that's how you application can accept user input, when you press a button, the `QApplication::processEvents` calls `YourFunction` which calls `QEventLoop::exec` which calls `QApplication::processEvents` ... which can again call `YourFunction` and this is just functions being called recursively, as for why the GUI is not blocked is because `QApplication::processEvents` calls other functions too that draw the GUI and handle user interaction.

Comment: @Jacob to the application there is no difference between "waiting for a button click to call a SLOT" and "wait for packet to be received to call a SLOT", both go in the same eventloop and both are dispatched using the same mechanism, so i would say QEventLoop is the same as any other language and framework, it just also handles GUI events too.

Comment: @AhmedAEK In reality, there is no "something like": QCoreApplication actually uses a pure, standard QEventLoop :-)

Comment: @Jacob a simple while loop is completely blocking, meaning that it prevents any event loop to process their events until it *allows* it, which is either by exiting the while loop completely, or by explicitly asking the application to process pending events. That kind of while loop is problematic because it doesn't *sleep*: it continuously loops unnecessarily occupying the CPU while doing practically nothing except from looping. A valid loop, instead, sleeps until something tells it to "wake up", which, for event loops, is whenever an event is dispatched to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your all great answers, @musicamante so I assume, because that answer was not given, that nested QeventLoop is running in the same thread. If I would start a new thread for some class and run QeventLoop there, I would not serve events from the main thread. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jacob A QEventLoop only receives events for (dispatched to) its own thread. A QEventLoop created in a thread will not receive user events, because they are always handled in the main thread. Note that, if you use QThread, it has its own QEventLoop (which is created and started in the new thread created by `exec()`, which is done right after calling `start()`) unless `run()` is overridden.